# How to call a plugin from command line?

Tags: calibre

How to, lets say, hyphen an ebook with Hyphenate This! plugin from command line?

Answer (score 0):

How to work with the Calibre command line can be found in this [manual](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/cli-index.html).

Use this command to show what you can do with [plugins](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/calibre-customize.html):

```
calibre-customize -h
```

I'm afraid *Hyphenate This!* is just a [GUI plugin](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=118764) without a command line interface.

(For more advanced work with plugins, look at [API](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/plugins.html) documentation.)

Comment: Do you know a way to convert and hyphen epub to azw3?